# ternary operator check null and set boolean using .equals at same time

Tags: java, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Is it possible to do something like this?

`dog.setIsBarkingIndicator(mailman.getIsAtDoor() != null && mailman.getIsAtDoor().equals("N") ? false : true);`

But for what I researched, this is basically the same as: `dog.setIsBarkingIndicator(mailman.getIsAtDoor() == null || !mailman.getIsAtDoor().equals("N"))`

So it actually sets it at false if its null or not equals to "N"? Did I understand correctly?

Is there any way to check the null without using the if condition?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid checking null here?

Comment: This was just an example I made, but in the actually application Im working, I can get a nullPointerException.

Comment: Perhaps the dog or the mailman variable is null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, your logical condition is basically like the following:

`mailman.getIsAtDoor() == null || !mailman.getIsAtDoor().equals("N")`

You can change the instance which performs `equal` operation. The one instance here is a constant string literal - that means it is never a null value, so it can always perform an equality operation. The condition you are looking for is here:

`!"N".equals(mailman.getIsAtDoor())`.

This approach does not require from you to check null value of the `mailman.getIsAtDoor()`.

Comment: Thats really clever. I was so focused in the "complicated" way, that I didn't even realise this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the dog or the mailman variable is null. So please try the following code:

```
if (dog != null && mailman != null)
{
  dog.setIsBarkingIndicator(!mailman.getIsAtDoor().equals("N"));
}
```